# Create a div for every row in a table

Tags: html

I have 1 table in my html. Now I want to create for every row a new div. In this div is a `<p>` which is in the first column of the first row. And the same for the second column in the first row. How can I do this?

Comment: Javascript and a for loop.  What have you tried, and what problem are you having?

Comment: I don‘t know how to how do that

Answer (score 0):

If your goal was to dynamically create it with an array of information heres my simplest approach:

[Quick JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b54m9Lja/9/)

Lets say you start with an empty table and an array with row arrays and string elements inside:

```html
<table id="target">
  <tr>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

```js
let myInfo = [
  ['A', 'B', 'C'],
  ['X', 'Y', 'Z'],
];
```

We select the table first:

```js
let table = document.querySelector('#target');
let tbody = table.querySelector('tbody');
```

Then we loop for each row in our `myInfo` array, create a div and append it to `tbody`

```js
myInfo.forEach((row) => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  tbody.appendChild(div);
});
```

Now for each row we create our `p` element as a cell. we set the innerHTML with the passed cell argument (the strings inside each row array) and append it to the row div we created in the outer scope.

```js
myInfo.forEach((row) => {
  let div = document.createElement('div');
  tbody.appendChild(div);

  row.forEach((cell) => {
    let p = document.createElement('p');
    p.innerHTML = cell;
    div.appendChild(p);
  });
});
```

last but not least we make the divs and paragraphs display semantically correct with css

```css
tbody > div {
  display: table-row;
}
tbody > div > p {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: That‘s great. But I want to show this information **from** the table **into** the div.

Comment: Not from a list into a table